# Sharepoint 2010 Workflow doesn't trigger automatically on first created item of the day

Tags: 2010, workflow, item

Everyday, on a particular site collection in my farm, the list workflow doesn't trigger automatically on the first created item in this list.

If I create a second item 2 seconds after the first one, workflow starts normally.

I'm working with my own account so it's not the system account problem that I see everywhere. I have no service packs installed on my server. Windows server 2008. Works fine on every other site collection.